What is the point of proof of correctness of NP-completeness?
In most the problems I am tasked to prove that a problem A is NP-complete. I show that B is in NP, then I reduce NP-hard problem A to B. Then I am required to prove that  a yes instance in B is a yes instance in A. But also it says that I need to prove that a yes instance in A will be a yes instance in A. This is a bit confusing because isn't it basically the same thing from another angle?
I also got this understanding that all yes instances in A will not be yes instances in B. Given that the reduction is from B to A, all yes instance inputs of A won't even be defined for B unless I also reduce A to B. What am I supposed to do when asked to prove that yes in A -> yes in B?

"need to prove that a yes instance in $A$ will be a yes instance in $A$." I guess the second $A$ should be a $B$.

Note that the second statement, "I need to prove that a yes instance in A will be a yes instance in B," is logically equivalent to "a no instance in B maps to a no instance in A" (by taking the contrapositive). So effectively, we are showing that a yes instance in B guarantees that we had a yes instance in A, and a no instance in B guarantees that we had a no instance in A.
One intuitive way to understand the necessity of this rigor is the following: suppose we try to prove that PATH (the problem of testing whether there is a path between two given nodes in a graph) is NP-complete. We say, "given a problem in NP, we map it to a trivial graph connecting two nodes by an edge, asking if there is an edge between these nodes." Well, all yes instances of the original problem will be correctly mapped to a yes instance of path. However, the no instances of the original problem will not be mapped to a no instance of PATH.
Therein lies the problem: if we weren't careful and only proved one of the two directions (the first one), we would conclude that PATH is NP-complete, and thus, since PATH is in P, P = NP! Alas, things are not so simple.
